# How to optimize lots of ng-repeats while using css grid

Tags: html, css, angularjs, grid-layout

So I want to make table with css grid where I have 5 columns and an unknown number of rows. I also have an element that pops up when a first column element is clicked. This poped element covers from column 2 up to 5. Reason for this is I want to maintain scroll position from all columns visible to only first column.

My problem is that with a bit more data **all these ng-repeats** get kind of slow. Is there a way to unify all these ng-repeats that are out of eachothers' scope without losing this separation of columns?

Doing it with ng-repeat-start/end required me to wrap the objects' data elements into a parent element, but that leaves me with auto generated rows AND cells, and I can't control the first COLUMN for example to make it scrollable on it's own or set a specific height.

(this is what can't be controlled)

```
<h1>Call List</h1>
<select>
    <option ng-repeat="list in vm.list">{{list.name}}</option>
</select>
<div class="call-list-grid" ng-init="vm.selected=false;">
    <div ng-click="vm.selected = !vm.selected" id="consumers" ng-repeat-start="list in vm.listdata">
        {{list.name}}</div>
    <div ng-if="!vm.selected" ng-click="vm.selected = vm.selected" id="status">{{list.status}}</div>
    <div ng-if="!vm.selected" ng-click="vm.selected = vm.selected" id="timezone">{{list.timezone}}</div>
    <div ng-if="!vm.selected" ng-click="vm.selected = vm.selected" id="time">{{list.time}}</div>
    <div ng-if="!vm.selected" ng-click="vm.selected = vm.selected" id="guide" ng-repeat-end>{{list.guide}}</div>

    <div ng-if="vm.selected" id="selected-consumer"></div>
</div>
```

This is the code I currently have and I'm trying to optimize

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Title header</h1>
    <select>
        <option ng-repeat="data in vm.data">{{list.name}}</option>
    </select>
    <div class="list-grid" id="grid" ng-class="{'selected' : vm.selected}"
         ng-init="vm.selected=false;">
        <div id="user" ng-class="{'user-selected' : vm.selected}">
            <div ng-click="vm.selectUser()" ng-repeat="list in vm.listdata">
               {{list.name}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="status">
            <div ng-if="!vm.selected" ng-class="{'user-selected' : vm.selected}"
                 ng-repeat="list in vm.listdata">
                {{list.status}}</div>
        </div>
        <div id="timezone">
            <div ng-if="!vm.selected" ng-class="{'user-selected' : vm.selected}"
                 ng-repeat="list in vm.listdata">
                {{list.timezone}}</div>
        </div>
        <div id="time">
            <div ng-if="!vm.selected" ng-class="{'user-selected' : vm.selected}"
                 ng-repeat="list in vm.listdata">
                {{list.time}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="person">
            <div ng-if="!vm.selected" ng-class="{'user-selected' : vm.selected}"
                 ng-repeat="list in vm.listdata">
                {{list.person}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div ng-if="vm.selected" id="selected">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.list-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto;
    row-gap: 2px;
    height: 77vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;

    &.consumer-selected {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
}

#user {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 2;

    // height: 100vh;
    // overflow: hidden;
    &.consumer-selected {
        overflow-y: auto;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        height: 77vh;
    }
}

#status {
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-column-end: 3;

    &.consumer-selected {
        display: none;
    }
}

#timzone {
    grid-column-start: 3;
    grid-column-end: 4;

    &.consumer-selected {
        display: none;
    }
}

#time {
    grid-column-start: 4;
    grid-column-end: 5;

    &.consumer-selected {
        display: none;
    }
}

#person{
    grid-column-start: 5;
    grid-column-end: 6;

    &.consumer-selected {
        display: none;
    }
}

#selected{
    background-color: rgb(177, 218, 177);
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-column-end: 6;
    grid-row: 1 / 50;
    height: 77vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use the filter limitTo so maybe i not beffer option but can be util for you, so u can use something like that.

```
<div class="container">
     <h1>Title header</h1>
      <select>
        <option ng-repeat="data in vm.data">{{list.name}}</option>
     </select>
    <div class="list-grid" id="grid" ng-class="{'selected' : vm.selected}" ng- 
          init="vm.selected=false;">
        <div id="user" ng-class="{'user-selected' : vm.selected}">
            <div ng-click="vm.selectUser()" ng-repeat="list in vm.listdata  | limitTo:quantity"> 
          {{list.name}}</div>
        </div>
        <div id="status">
            <div ng-if="!vm.selected" ng-class="{'user-selected' : vm.selected}" 
       ng-repeat="list in vm.listdata  | limitTo:quantity">
                {{list.status}}</div>
        </div>
        <div id="timezone">
            <div ng-if="!vm.selected" ng-class="{'user-selected' : vm.selected}" 
         ng-repeat="list in vm.listdata  | limitTo:quantity">
                {{list.timezone}}</div>
        </div>
        <div id="time">
            <div ng-if="!vm.selected" ng-class="{'user-selected' : vm.selected}" 
          ng-repeat="list in vm.listdata  | limitTo:quantity">
                {{list.time}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="person">
            <div ng-if="!vm.selected" ng-class="{'user-selected' : vm.selected}" 
             ng-repeat="list in vm.listdata | limitTo:quantity">
                {{list.person}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div ng-if="vm.selected" id="selected">

        </div>
       <button ng-click="getMore()">More</button>
       </div>
    </div>


//your controller 

  $scope.getMore = function(){
    $scope.quantity += 10 //or 20, 30
 }
```

You can use this with scrolling too.